# Resolving promises inside for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to read a JSON object using a for loop to format the JSON data and send it back to the client by putting the formatted response into a model object.

Inside for loop, i am dealing with two promises based upon few conditions. There are two functions, each having a promise returned.How can I get my final data after all the promises are resolved? Thanks in advance.

```
for (var i = 0, i<jsonData.length; i++){
   if(someCOndition){
       getSomeData().then(function(data){
          //some operation using data
       })
   }
  if(someOtherCOndition){
       getSomeOtherData().then(function(data){
          //some operation using data
       })
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you only trying to know when all the promises in the loop are done or are you trying to collect some data from all the promises and have all that data at the end?  Your code is a little too much pseudo-code for us to understand what the full goal of this code is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Promise.all([ promise1, promise2 ])` ([Promise.all() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)) in case of standard JS Promises (ES2015+). It returns a new promise, which gets resolved once all passed promises get resolved. But be aware - it will get rejected immediately when at least one promise gets rejected (it won't wait for any other promise).

Answer (score 6):

You might do as follows;

```js
var promises = [],
  JSONData_1 = ["chunk_11","chunk_12","chunk_13"],
  JSONData_2 = ["chunk_21","chunk_22","chunk_23"],
 getJSONData = (b,i) => new Promise((resolve,reject) => setTimeout(_ => b ? resolve(JSONData_1[i])
                                                                          : resolve(JSONData_2[i]),1000));

for (var i = 0; i < JSONData_1.length; i++){
   if(Math.random() < 0.5) promises.push(getJSONData(true,i));
   else promises.push(getJSONData(false,i));
}
Promise.all(promises)
       .then(a => console.log(a));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery.when().

```
  var deferredList = [];
    for (var i = 0, i<jsonData.length; i++){
       if(someCOndition){

         deferredList.push(getSomeData().then(function(data){
         //some operation using data
         }))
        }
   if(someOtherCOndition){

       taskList.push(getSomeOtherData().then(function(data){
        //some operation using data
       }))
    }
   }
 JQuery.when(taskList).done(function(){
      // final to do..
 }).fail(){
    // even if single one fails ! be aware of this
   }
```

[jQuery.when() MDN](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/#jQuery-when-deferreds)

Comment: Solved my issue. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple ways. We can also use for of loop with async..await to get the result synchronously while looping, if that is a requirement. Something like this:

```
function downloadPage(url) {    
    return Promise.resolve('some value'); 
}

async function () {    
    for(let url of urls) {
       let result = await downloadPage(url);
       // Process the result 
       console.log(result);    
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this..

```
var arr=[],arr2=[];
for (var i = 0, i<jsonData.length; i++){
   if(someCOndition){
       //push onto the array inputs for getSomeData()
       arr.push(jsonData[i]);
   }
  if(someOtherCOndition){
       arr2.push(jsonData[i]);
   }
}

processArr(0);
processArr2(0);

function processArr(idx){
    if (idx>=arr.length) {
        //done
    }
    else {
        getSomeData().then(function(data){
          // some operation using data
          // optionally store in a results array

          // recurse
          processArr(idx+1)

       })
    }
}

function processArr2(idx){
    if (idx>=arr2.length) {
        //done
    }
    else {
        getSomeotherData().then(function(data){
          // some operation using data

          // recurse
          processArr2(idx+1)
       })
    }
}
```